# MySQL: SUM two UNIONed tables (4x SUM in one result)

Tags: mysql

i have to SELECTs, UNIONed in one simple query...

```
SELECT description_x, a, b, c, d from table a WHERE person_id = 1
UNION
SELECT description_y, e ,f ,g ,h from table b WHERE person_id = 1
```

... a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h are all integers. How can i SUM them, that the result will look like this...

```
row 1: description_x |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d
row 2: description_y |  e  |  f  |  g  |  h
row 3: summary       | a+e | b+f | c+g | d+h
```

...please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems odd that c would have any kind of relationship to g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another `union` to it which will do the aggregation.

```
select description_x, a, b, c, d from table a where person_id = 1
union all
select description_y, e ,f ,g ,h from table b where person_id = 1
union all
select 'summary', sum(a), sum(b), sum(c), sum(d) from (
    select a, b, c, d from table a where person_id = 1
    union all
    select e ,f ,g ,h from table b where person_id = 1
) t
```

We wouldn't need to rewrite the same query again if MySQL supported CTEs (which, as mentioned in the comments, is coming in MySQL 8 onwards).

Comment: That is exactly what I wal looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(a) as a,sum(b) as b,sum(c) as c,sum(d) as d from (
SELECT description_x, a, b, c, d from table a WHERE person_id = 1
UNION All
SELECT description_y, e ,f ,g ,h from table b WHERE person_id = 1
)T
```